# Linq Left Outer Join Two Tables on Two Fields

Tags: linq

How do I left outer join two tables on two fields in linq?
I have a sql:

```
    select a.*, b.* from courselist as a
                                 left outer join  Summary as b
                                 on a.subject = b.Subject and a.catalog = 
    b.Catalogno 
                                 where a.degree_id = 1 
                                 order by a.sequenceNo
```

Below is my linq query, but there is error underline "join", failed in the call to "Groupjoin". I don't know how to correct that.

```
    var searchResults = (from a in db.courselist
                                   join b in db.Summary on
                                  new { a.subject,a.catalog } equals
                                   new { b.Subject, b.Catalogno } into ab

                                  where  a.degree_id == 1 
                                  orderby a.degree_sequenceNo
                                  from b  in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Courselist = a,
                                      Summary = b
                                  }
                                ).ToList();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your code again,
I found it's fault
you just need to specify join parameters name like this:

```
new { suject = a.subject, catalog = a.catalog } equals
new { suject = b.subject, catalog = b.Catalogno } into ab
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are my savior :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the reference, the query doesn't have an error
try to use this:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: The error message is "LINQ - 'The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'." but I checked all the data types are match.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue when people start using LINQ is that they keep thinking in the SQL way, they design the SQL query first and then translate it to LINQ. You need to learn how to think in the LINQ way and your LINQ query will become neater and simpler. For instance, in your LINQ you don't need joins. You should use **Associations/Navigation Properties** instead. Check [this post](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/) for more details.

There should be a relationship between `courselist` and `Summary`, in which case, you can access `Summary` through `courselist` like this:

```
var searchResults = (from a in db.courselist
                     where  a.degree_id == 1 
                     orderby a.degree_sequenceNo
                     select new {
                         Courselist = a,
                         Summary = a.Summary
                     }).ToList();
```

If there is no relationship between the two, then you should reconsider your design.

Comment: I am trying to get Summary table "description" field that's the reason I want to join two tables. Courselist has some records without description so I need to do a left outer join.

Comment: Yes, but if they are designed properly, there must be a relationship between the two, so when you write `a.Summary` or `a.Summary.Description`, it will automatically do the left join for you. It is smart enough to tell from the relationship what type of join is required. You can check the generated SQL of my answer and you will see that it uses `LEFT JOIN`. Try it, is there a `Summary` property on the `courselist`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I read some posts said it would do the left join automatically but I tested it and it does not. So I used the someone's suggestion new { suject = a.subject, catalog = a.catalog } equals
new { suject = b.subject, catalog = b.Catalogno } into ab and it does the trick.

Comment: Yes, if doesn't use `LEFT JOIN` in your case, that's an indication that the design is incorrect. Check your database tables & relationships and fix them instead of trying to force LINQ into using something that will result in not using indexes and the performance will take a big hit.